# Error during Testing Contract using Ethereum-bridge for oraclize

Tags: solidity, oracles

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to test (truffle test) my contract which uses Oraclize API 0.5 to get the ledger random from oraclize (datasource = "random"). I'm using solidity 0.5.0 compiler, and this is the error trace:

```
Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-deployer\src\deployment.js:364:1
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v11.6.0
```

I've tried to run another contract example (RandomExample) but it throws the same error, which means the error is not in contract but probably in the way it queries ethereum-bridge and Ganache (v1.2.3). I used the following code to initialize ethereum-bridge:

```
.\ethereum-bridge.cmd -H localhost:7545 --loglevel:debug --dev -a 9
```

any ideas what could be the possible error? the error is throwing when the following code is called inside the contract:

```
queryId = oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, callbackGas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the **random datasource** is currently available **ONLY** on the Ethereum mainnet and on all Ethereum public testnets (Rinkeby, Kovan, Ropsten-revival); and it is not integrated yet with private blockchains/testrpc/browser-solidity-vmmode, you will need to get a *mnemonic passphrase* and an *infura key* to make the example work.

If you look at the branch `new-truffle-random-example` of the Oraclize GitHub Repo `ethereum-example`, this RandomExample maybe a good alternative for you:
https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/new-truffle-random-example/solidity/truffle-examples/random-datasource.
The readme is complete of all the instructions to make it succeed.